# How to allow xserver to draw windows from specified host?

Tags: ubuntu, x11, remote, x-server

I have computers `lagrangian` and `pterosaur` in my `LAN`. I have configured

```
DISPLAY=pterosaur:0
```

on `lagrangian`. Now I login to `lagrangian` and want to run

```
xcalc &
```

so that it was shown on `pterosaur` screen. Unfortunately, it complains

```
Error: Can't open display: pterosaur:0
```

This is probably because `pterosaur`'s x-server doesn't have `lagrangian` in it's white list. How to put it there?

**UPDATE**

I don't want to use X forwarding feature of SSH.

**UPDATE 2**

Transcript of session on `lagrangian`:

```
dims@lagrangian:~$ export DISPLAY=pterosaur:0
dims@lagrangian:~$ ping pterosaur
PING pterosaur.inthemoon.net (192.168.10.77) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from pterosaur.inthemoon.net (192.168.10.77): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=9.65 ms
64 bytes from pterosaur.inthemoon.net (192.168.10.77): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=2.26 ms
64 bytes from pterosaur.inthemoon.net (192.168.10.77): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=8.93 ms
^C
--- pterosaur.inthemoon.net ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 2.269/6.951/9.653/3.323 ms
dims@lagrangian:~$ xcalc &
[1] 13206
dims@lagrangian:~$ Error: Can't open display: pterosaur:0

[1]+  Exit 1                  xcalc
```

**UPDATE 3**

Transcript of session with `xhost`:

```
dims@pterosaur:~/.ssh$ sudo xhost +
[sudo] password for dims: 
access control disabled, clients can connect from any host
dims@pterosaur:~/.ssh$ ssh lagrangian
Welcome to Ubuntu ...
Last login...
dims@lagrangian:~$ export DISPLAY=pterosaur:0
dims@lagrangian:~$ xcalc &
[1] 13722
dims@lagrangian:~$ Error: Can't open display: pterosaur:0

[1]+  Exit 1                  xcalc
```

**UPDATE 4**

Executing this on pterosaur didn't help:

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 6000 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 6001 -j ACCEPT
```

also I tried

```
export DISPLAY=pterosaur:1
```

on remote host.

**UPDATE 5**

After I created file

```
dims@pterosaur:/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d$ cat 100-custom.conf 
[SeatDefaults] 
xserver-allow-tcp=true
```

error message changed to

```
$ xcalc &
[1] 2003
No protocol specified
Error: Can't open display: pterosaur:0
```

Comment: How do you login to `lagrangian` from `pterosaur` ? Are you using `ssh -X` (and then, don't explicitly set `DISPLAY`) ?

Comment: No I don't use tunneling. I wan't to draw over LAN

Comment: I'm not sure `ssh` should be called tunelling

Comment: Whatever you call it, I don't want to use it. I want `xcalc` started on `lagrangian` draws it's window on `pterosaur`'s screen according to `DISPLAY` variable

Comment: Please edit your question to improve it. Why do you call `ssh` a tunelling application (it is not one)? Explain exactly how to you do the remote login and why `ssh`  should not be used.

Comment: My advice is to consult the  xauth(1) manpage. I'm now not perfectly firm with it to give an immediate answer, but this is the tool you want probably to use.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch excluding of X forwarding via ssh is a requirement of the question.

Comment: Please explain why `ssh` is not suitable, and **how exactly you do the *remote* login**. Or do you have *both* physical keyboards and screens of `pterosaur` and of `lagrangian` in front of you?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch yes I have both physical keyboards and screens in front of me

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I don't do any remote logins

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, there should be no need for a *remote* login. @Dims, my guess is that you will also need to enable TCP in the X server (I believe this was enabled by default until some years ago. the `Xorg` manpage here now says "TCP/IP [...] This connection type is usually disabled by default, but may be enabled with the -listen option (see the Xserver(1) man page for details).")

Comment: @Dims, (And then set the permissions accordingly using `xhost`, as in @ivanivan's answer below.)

Comment: @njsg: OP should have explained more his configuration (what he wrote in comments should have initially been in the question).

Comment: *Why* don't you want to use SSH? It's not the only way, but it's the only way that's easy to set up.

Comment: @Gilles I am using SSH, but the question is not about it; I need to state constraints in order to receive answer I need, because people tend to answer something they like

Comment: @Gilles of course we can note some disadvantages of using X-forwarding: for example, if you close ssh session, all your windows become broken. I need windows appear and work normally as if programs run on local machine. This was great advantage of XWindow for many years and no reason to kill it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use `xhost`, and depending on your security needs you can use `xhost +` to allow all hosts to use your display, or you can specify which host via `xhost +machinename`.  Of course, whatever `machinename` need to be in `/etc/hosts` or resolvable via DNS lookup.

Comment: This didn't work. How to debug this approach?

Comment: @Dims - edit your question and put in exactly what you entered on each box, and exactly what error you got

Comment: I have executed `xhost +lagrangian` on `pterosaur`. What else should/can I do?

Comment: See my `UPDATE 3`

Comment: @Dims Is the X server on `pterosaur` listening to network connections at all? Is there any firewall blocking that connection?

Comment: @njsg this is the question! what is required for this thing work!

Comment: @Dims Other than possibly dealing with firewall rules if there is any, I'd guess you need to pass the `-listen tcp` option to the X server on `pterosaur` (and possibly remove `-nolisten tcp`?). How you do this depends on how are you starting the X server. `startx`? Some graphical login manager?

Comment: @njsg it's `Ubuntu`, it starts itself somehow

Comment: @Dims any chance [a question from 2011 on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34657/how-to-make-x-org-listen-to-remote-connections-on-port-6000) or something linked from there is of any use? Perhaps the comments from 2015? (I don't use Ubuntu myself.)

Answer (score 0):

Use [ssh(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ssh.1.html) to login from `pterosaur` to `lagrangian` with `-X` so on `pterosaur` do

```
 ssh -X lagrangian
```

See also [xauth](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.0/doc/xauth.1.html) and the unsecure [xhost](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.0/doc/xhost.1.html) (which you might run as `xhost +`)

Read [Xsecurity(7)](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.0/doc/Xsecurity.7.html) and look into the `Xorg*log` file (probably under `/var/log/`) for error messages. Read [more](https://wiki.debian.org/Xorg) about [Xorg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.Org_Server). You may need to configure the way it was started (do you use `xinit`, `startx`, `gdm`, ...?), so read [Xorg(1)](ftp://www.x.org/pub/X11R6.8.0/doc/Xorg.1.html), [xorg.conf(5)](ftp://www.x.org/pub/X11R6.8.0/doc/xorg.conf.5.html), [Xserver(1)](ftp://www.x.org/pub/X11R6.8.0/doc/Xserver.1.html) and perhaps remove the `-nolisten tcp` option to your `X` *server* (and you only know how it was started).

<sup>(AFAIU, remote X11 is becoming deprecated without authentication, but I leave you to check that. It could depend upon your particular X11 configuration)</sup>

PS. `ssh` is *not* a tunnelling application and with `-X` manages the remote displaying. You might need to configure it on both sides (but most default configurations are ok). BTW, I believe that `ssh -X` is the simplest way to get that these days.

Comment: No, I don't want to use tunneling.

Comment: Okay, it's forwarding and I don't want to use it.

Comment: `xhost` didn't help